# Storing returned API data in a variable outside an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I don’t know what I’m doing wrong but I can’t seem to store an API response that I’m returning from an async function to a variable outside the function. I keep getting a promise. I want to use the returned data in ejs.

Here is the code:

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  const { city } = req.query
  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${api}`
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(url)
      return data; 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
 
  const weatherData = getData()

  console.log(weatherData) // Promise { <pending> }
 
  res.render('index') 
})
```

Comment: your need `await getData()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I did but I get - SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: oh right, you will need async at here too `async (req,res)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `async`/`await` to halt the execution of the function:

```
app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
  ...
  const weatherData = await getData()

  console.log(weatherData) // Data
  ...
})
```